# Custom filter and export filtered data into excel sheet not working in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, excel, ajax, datatables

I have data table with search filed. I am trying to filter table using data range and order status. I want to filter table also using range and status and also want to export into excel sheet. Code is working for only search and simple export (Not filtered data).

Thanks

This is my file (View, Controller and Model)

View:-

```
<a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="<?php echo base_url()?>order/createXLS"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export Data</a>
<div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title" >Custom Filter : </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form id="form-filter" method="POST" action="order/ajax_list" class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="FirstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="from">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="LastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="to">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="LastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="LastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <button type="button" id="btn-filter" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btn-reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>  
        </div> 
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="mytable"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th width="80px">No</th> 
                <th>Order Number</th> 
                <th>Service Date</th>
                <th>Service Location</th> 
                <th>Customer Name</th> 
                <th>Contact Number</th> 
                <th>Order Status</th>
                <th>Payment Status</th> 
                <th>Action</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
            <?php 
            $start = 0; 
            foreach ($job_positions_data as $job_positions) 
            { 
                ?> 
                <tr> 
                    <td> 
                        <?php echo ++$start ?> 
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        <?php echo $job_positions->order_number ?> 
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        <?php echo $job_positions->service_date ?> 
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <?php if($job_positions->service_location == 1)
                        {
                            echo 'vkool_branch';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo 'customer_location' ;
                        }
                        ?> 
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        <?php echo $job_positions->firstname ?> 
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        <?php echo $job_positions->contact_number ?> 
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        <?php if($job_positions->order_status == 0)
                        {
                            echo 'Action Pending';
                        }
                        elseif($job_positions->order_status == 1)
                        {
                            echo 'Under Process' ;
                        }
                        elseif($job_positions->order_status == 2)
                        {
                            echo 'Cancelled' ;
                        }
                        elseif($job_positions->order_status == 3)
                        {
                            echo 'Completed' ;
                        }
                        elseif($job_positions->order_status == 4)
                        {
                            echo 'Refund' ;
                        }
                        ?>  
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        <?php if( $job_positions->payment_status == 1) 
                        {
                            echo 'Pending (Pay at Store)';
                        }
                        elseif($job_positions->payment_status == 0)
                        {
                            echo 'Pending (Pay Online)';
                        }
                        elseif($job_positions->payment_status == 14)
                        {
                           echo 'Paid';
                        }?> 
                    </td> 
                    <td style="text-align:center" width="200px"> 
 <a href="javascript:view_order(<?php echo $job_positions->id; ?>)"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                <?php 
            } 
            ?> 
        </tbody> 
    </table> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#mytable").dataTable(); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Controller : -

```
public function createXLS() {

    $fileName = 'data-'.time().'.xlsx';  
    require_once APPPATH . "/third_party/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php";
    $orderInfo = $this->Order_model->get_For_Export();
    $ordervalue = json_encode($orderInfo, true);

    /*echo '<pre>';
    print_r($orderInfo);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;*/
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // set Header
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'S.No');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Order Number');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Service Location');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'First Name');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'Last Name');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F1', 'Contact_No');    
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G1', 'Order Status');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H1', 'Payment Status');

    // Style
    $style = array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        ),
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true,
            'color' => array('rgb' => '2F4F4F'),
            'size' => 20,
        ),
    );
    $styleHeading = array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        ),
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true,
            'size' => 15,
        ),
    );






    // set Row
    $rowCount = 2;
    foreach ($orderInfo as $element) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $rowCount, $element['id']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $rowCount, $element['order_number']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $rowCount, $element['service_location']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D' . $rowCount, $element['firstname']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E' . $rowCount, $element['lastname']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F' . $rowCount, $element['contact_number']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G' . $rowCount, $element['order_status']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H' . $rowCount, $element['payment_status']);
        $rowCount++;
    }

    // download file
    $filename = "jobSummery". date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").".xls";
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  
    $objWriter->save('php://output');  
}


public function list_view()
{
    $job_positions = $this->Order_model->get_all(); 
    $data = array( 
        'job_positions_data' => $job_positions 
    ); 
    $this->load->view('order/index', $data);
}
```

Model :-

```
public function get_all() 
{ 
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->from('tbl_order');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result; 
}
public function get_For_Export() 
{ 
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->from('tbl_order');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: Unless you're proposing to do the filtering client side, I would be tempted to start with the raw sql, and then figure out how to 'reverse engineer' that into your code

Comment: How can we do server side?